# Safari and Firefox: Poorly performing SWF stopping other SWF on page

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, firefox, safari

I have a swf on the page that's performing poorly, taking a lot of CPU mostly for rendering. While that's running my 1px by 1px swf handling socket data is stopping execution. Enter frame events do not occur and timers also don't fire in that socket swf. However, ExternalInterface calls to the swf work. If the poorly performing swf is removed from the page or it starts performing better the socket swf will suddenly get enter frames and timer events. This doesn't happen on Chrome but does occur on Safari and FF.

Any insight would be very appreciated!

Comment: FF works as a single process, and all Flash is running in (another) single process. No way to alter that until some next FF release - they plan to have more than a single process eventually. You should press on that SWF's developers to yield more often, or if you cannot, block that SWF for performance reasons.

Comment: **_"...This doesn't happen on Chrome but does occur on Safari and FF"_**. I bet Chrome is running Pepper Flash version (PPAPI) and the others are using older Flash Plugin code (NPAPI)... Don't know about Safari but you should search : **How to enable PPAPI Flash in Firefox**.